# How do you properly test for a bad solenoid?

Tags: solenoid, repair

As a sidebar to [this other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/283896/how-to-diagnose-a-possible-faulty-circuit-board-on-a-laser-printer), how do you properly test a solenoid? The resistance is within spec, could a solenoid fail in ways that still show the normal internal resistance?

Comment: Sure it can fail. It's an electromechanical device, so except the electrical failures there might be mechanical ones.

Comment: A shorted turn or group of turns on a solenoid will vastly reduce it's magnetic capabilities but hardly affect its resistance. Mechanical problems are more likely.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon A shorted turn (or even a few turns) won't affect the magnetic field of a solenoid much.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany You are probably right. I was thinking in terms of transformers with reasonably closed magnetic paths, where a shorted turn can be extremely exciting.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Yes. When you think of ampere-turns it's pretty easy to see that it won't affect it statically but what happens when the field is changing is much less straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the core from the solenoid it will measure the same resistance but won't behave the same. The moving plunger could be gunked up and sticky. A return spring could wear out or come off.

But if the solenoid looks okay mechanically and the resistance measures okay, it's **probably** okay.

Note that it's not uncommon for coils, especially fine ones, to fail open or intermittent. In the latter case, the coil could measure okay but open up when it warms up or is exposed to cold or hot temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

A DC solenoid may work OK with a few shorted turns, but the inductance will certainly change. This might appear as a much higher than normal initial current surge. A good way to test it would be an LCR meter to determine the reactance. An AC solenoid with shorted turns would draw higher than normal current, and probably would produce audible noise as well as possibly some RF if there is internal arcing.